# LiveCode- Mobile Differences

Tags: livecode

How to automatically set the size of the platform/game from different sizes of devices?

I have a tutorial for Mobile Differences in Livecode, I have tried to copy everything from the tutorial but I cannot get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle most of your screen sizes buy using

```
Set the fullscreenmode of this stack to *mode*
Set the fullscreen of this stack to true
```

Where *mode* is one of the supported modes. (Check the dictionary or the [Tutorial](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/15262/l/565745-how-do-i-make-my-app-scale-to-fit-the-screen-on-all-devices)) This will handle different sizes with the same aspect ratio good, but if you are to create an iPad / iPhone hybrid my suggestion is to create two different layouts as users kind of expect different layouts on the different screen sizes.

There is also a Tutorial [from LiveCode](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/15262/l/565745-how-do-i-make-my-app-scale-to-fit-the-screen-on-all-devices) on the subject.